# Should I include the app's logo in a mobile app's action bar?

Tags: mobile, logos

I am making a mobile application and currently I have a custom action bar with just text describing the functionality of the current page and a back button to return the user to the previous page. I am trying to promote my product through the logo but it might be forced if I include it in the action bar. Would including the logo in the action bar be forced and just add extra confusion?

Comment: If the icon would be a button that triggers some functionality (relevant) it could be a nice way to include it, but this is more like an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the terminology you use, I believe you are referring to Android, so let me focus on this platform first.

Action bar recommendations were, back then, to display the app icon:
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

> [image: Action Bar]
>
> App icon The app icon establishes your app's identity. It can be
>   replaced with a different logo or branding if you wish. Important: If
>   the app is currently not displaying the top-level screen, be sure to
>   display the Up caret to the left of the app icon, so the user can
>   navigate up the hierarchy. For more discussion of Up navigation, see
>   the Navigation pattern

This approach, however, has changed with the introduction of Material Design:
https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html

> [image: App bar]
>
> The app bar, formerly known as the action bar in Android, is a special
>   kind of toolbar that’s used for branding, navigation, search, and
>   actions.
>
> The nav icon at the left side of the app bar can be:
>
> A control to open a navigation drawer. An up arrow for navigating
>   upward through your app’s hierarchy. Omitted entirely if no navigation
>   is required from this screen. The title in the app bar reflects the
>   current page. It can be an app title, page title, or a page filter.
>
> Icons on the right side of the app bar are app-related actions. The
>   menu icon opens the overflow menu, which contains secondary actions
>   and menu items like help, settings, and feedback.

For iOS, I think it is also uncommon, however apps like Medium, Trello or Skype do include it in the top bar - but I believe it is rather due to branding than something that would allow the recognition in the future.

**Wrap-up:**

Of course, opinions may vary but I think it will add **more clutter and confusion cost than the app recognition gain**, so it is obsolete. If a User has already downloaded the app, it is enough for him/her to see it in the launcher.

However, there is one case in which I think it would be valuable. Let us say this is an Android app that is not visible anywhere in the launcher (e.g. a keyboard settings pane, often removed from the launcher screen and only left in the drawer). Or something that is triggered strictly from a widget, or notification, without an actual app icon. Then it may be valuable to show it. Still, I believe these are really rare occasions.